# What would be the best way to get multiple context root for a war file in websphere application server?

Tags: websphere, war

Would renaming war file be a advisable solution to get various context root in web sphere application server?

Answer (score 2):

To have the same war running under multiple context roots, that war will need to be deployed multiple times with different context roots specified.  see http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp4583.pdf page 14 step 11.

The best way in my option to deal with your need is to front your websphere app and use the mod_rewrite directive to intercept any url pattern with the "context roots" you need and rewrite them to ONE app/context root defined on websphere.  Here is a resource to do that: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/ihsdiag/plugin_alter_uri.html.

Comment: If the only thing you want is multiple paths to the same app, yes, use mod_rewrite (or something like it). You don't want to use extra resources and have to maintain two copies of the same app just to respond to multiple paths. However, note that internally constructed URLs that point back to the application may all go to one of those two paths.